# Trying to use __attribute__ in a #define macro to support MSVC and G++, having compile issues

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, g++

In my project I have a function that behaves similarly to `sprintf`, and I would like to enable compiler warnings if there is a parameter mismatch in the format string. I know that this is not possible in MSVC, but because my project is compiled with both MSVC and G++, I wanted to implement a platform-independent macro that adds the necessary __attribute__ to the function on G++. To achieve this, I wrote this macro:

```cpp
#if WIN32
    #define ATTR_PRINTF_CHECK(formatIndex, firstParamIndex)
#else
    #define ATTR_PRINTF_CHECK(formatIndex, firstParamIndex) \
        __attribute__ ((format (printf, formatIndex, firstParamIndex)))
#endif
```

If the compiler is MSVC (Win32), then this should evaluate to nothing. If it's G++, it should be replaced with the `__attribute__` specifier. However when I try to compile the following function, it fails with both compilers:

```cpp
void Log(CLogSeverity _severity, const char *format, ...) ATTR_PRINTF_CHECK(3, 4);
```

On linux (G++) the compiler says the following: (Yes, those exact characters after 'expected')

```
logger.h:39:61: error: expected â€˜;â€™ at end of member declaration
void Log(CLogSeverity _severity, const char *format, ...) ATTR_PRINTF_CHECK(3, 4);
```

If I compile on MSVC, it gives me this error:

```
error C3646: 'ATTR_PRINTF_CHECK': unknown override specifier
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2059: syntax error: '('
// and a bunch of other garbage
```

Am I misunderstanding the way `#define` macros work in C/C++? Am I not allowed to use them to insert compiler-specific attributes?

Comment: The macro is spelled `_WIN32` (the version without `_` is sometimes defined too, but I'm not sure when exactly). But it's not the right macro anyway (GCC exists on Windows too!). Use `_MSC_VER` to detect MSVC. As for the GCC error, [can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/d98G4T4E7).

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/jobfbqr1E) - it should be `ATTR_PRINTF_CHECK(2, 3)` with your current arguments though to properly work.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am using CLion with Visual Studio 2022/MSVC and WSL/G++ toolchains. I tested both of the godbolt snippets that you guys posted, and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: It's likely that the problem is within CLion. I should have tested in raw g++ before I posted. Now that I did, it compiles. I'll try to contact JetBrains if I can't figure it out. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of this problem. My `ATTR_PRINTF_CHECK` macro was defined in a different header file, which apparently wasn't included in the current header. So both compilers were trying to interpret the macro as a special attribute.

The reason why I didn't figure this out sooner is because my IDE (CLion) didn't warn me that the macro doesn't exist, and even highlighted it as a valid macro, along with intellisense and ctrl-click navigation.